# Cordova jquery window.location loading page relative path unexpectedly changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

Had an old phonegap app that worked fine (using jquery mobile). Updated to the latest Cordova (as of 11/11/15), updated jquery 2.1.4 and jquery mobile 1.4.5. The app starts off working just fine but multiple pages into it there seems to be a problem loading a new local url.

I am using `window.location.href = path` which works fine for a few pages looking at network logs I see things like "Navigated to file:///android_asset/www/dashboard.html", "Navigated to file:///android_asset/www/study_text.html" but then all the sudden I will load a new page and get "GET file:///android_asset/quiz.html net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" (the www folder is mising)

It looks like the url it is fetching sometimes has the www/ and sometimes does not. All the files are in the root of www and the base href is set to ".". All the url paths it is given are relative but do not include folders since they are all in the root together. So the real issue is, why does the file location change in javascript I guess? I always request a file like window.location.href = "a.html" "b.html" "c.html"; Most of the time the files are referenced just fine "file:///android_asset/www/a.html" but out of the blue they will start to get referenced like "file:///android_asset/a.html". Does anyone have any idea why?

-- UPDATE --
So a temporary solution I seemed to have some success with is to test via ajax if the file exists and change the location depending. However I shouldn't have to do this and I am not sure if it will always work when I switch over to iOS and Windows phone testing. So I still need to actually find out why the path is changing on me.

```
 $.ajax({
        url:path,
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function()
        {
            window.location.href = "www/"+path;
        },
        success: function()
        {
            window.location.href = path;
        }
    });
```